# Any way to change a value in a variable which is defined with const qualifier in c?

Tags: c

One thing I got to know now.The question is about the `const` qualifier in C. In my program I want to change the value of a variable which is defined with a const qualifier.

For example:

```
int main()
{
const int i=40;
i=50 ;  // error
}
```

But is there any way to change the value of i in the above example.Please let me know it.
Thank you

Comment: "I want to change the value of a variable which is defined with a const qualifier"  It sounds like you may not understand the purpose of `const`.

Comment: @James McNellis: C is defined in a such a way that sometimes you have to define a variable with a `const` qualifier but cannot assign a value to it (for example a complex data structure containing self-referencing pointers). you want the variable to be `const` but then you are stuck...

Comment: A question for you to ponder.  Why would you want to do that?  You can, but why?

Comment: @Adrien:  I do not understand your comment.  If you are going to need to modify an object, don't const-qualify it.

Comment: @Adrien: In that case you may have a pointer-to-const which you need to cast to get to the object, but the underlying pointed-to object was not defined with a const qualifier. There is absolutely no point in trying to modify objects defined with a const qualifier since it invokes UB and **does not work** (on most implementations).

Comment: i know how to do it i expected any new answers from you but you didnt say the one i know. There is another way you can change without any undefined behaviour i just wanted to test you guys ..

Comment: So when you said you "got to know now", you were lying? If you're posing a puzzle, say so ... it's unethical to jerk people around.

Answer (score 7):

In any program that has well-defined behavior, `i` cannot be modified.

C99 §6.7.3 ("Type Qualifiers")/5 states plainly:

> If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use
>   of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undeﬁned.

`i` is an object defined with a const-qualified type (`const int`).  It is a non-modifiable lvalue:  you cannot modify it because it is const-qualified.  The only way to modify it would be to use a cast to remove the const-qualification, which would cause the program to exhibit undefined behavior.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, you probably *shouldn't* be doing this.

Secondly, yes you can if you had to by taking its address and referencing it:

```
const int i = 40;
*(int*)&i = 50;
// i is now 50
```

Thirdly, please, please do not do this.

Edit: this, as others pointed out, exhibits undefined behavior. You're assuming that your compiler will store this value in an addressable location, which it doesn't have to. (A constant value can be replaced by its immediate value and make "taking address of it" not mean anything.) You were warned.

Comment: Is this "well-defined" in C or an implementation detail?

Comment: These answers make me feel like I know nothing.

Comment: Any program that does this exhibits undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways.

First is a way that you aren't interested in.  The standard allows this to happen but you probably can't control it so you aren't really interested.  The standard says you can define something like

```
const volatile int *pSomething;
```

because the implementation might change the thing that is pointed to (for example it might be a timer) but you can prohibit your program from changing it.

Second is a way that you are interested in, but the standard doesn't allow it.  yan already gave an answer like this.

```
*(int*)&i
```

is a modifiable lvalue according to the rules of what is a modifiable lvalue.  However, if you actually try to modify this lvalue, you violate the standard because the actual object i is defined as const.  The result is undefined behaviour.  The implementation might do what you want, or it might leave i unchanged, it might abort your program, or it might format your hard drive.

Here is a way to do what you might want to do.

```
int theRealI;
const int *pTheRealI = &theRealI;
#define i (*pTheRealI)
```

Then i will be read-only, but if you want to modify theRealI you can.